# Can I re-ask a question if it hasn't been answered?

Tags: discussion, questions, old-questions

So I notice that some questions simply go unanswered. Due to the volume of questions asked, sometimes these questions go away from the front page fairly quickly, and then they are never seen or heard from again. If such an event occurs, can one re-ask the question?

Comment: Also related: [How do i get attention fot old unsanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: It might be interesting to note that you cannot mark a question as duplicate of a question that has no upvoted or accepted answer.

Comment: The answers at [As a new user without much rep, what should I do if someone else has already asked a question I have, but it has no answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306242/as-a-new-user-without-much-rep-what-should-i-do-if-someone-else-has-already-ask) go into much better detail.

Answer (score 35):

You can always try **editing** the question, which bumps it to the top of the front page again.  Take the opportunity to change the subject or the question body to make it more clear, and perhaps someone will answer this time.

Comment: Agree. The no duplicates rule is a good thing.

Answer (score 20):

If your question remains unanswered, you can always try offering a bounty. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483019/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow/483070#483070) regarding the bounty system.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of people follow tags more than the front pags, so if you tag your question reasonably it should still stand a good chance of being seen, even if somebody is doing a tag update (and owning the front page).

Additionally:

- there is the "Community" user who will periodically prod your question
- you can edit it a few times to get it back to the front
- or offer a bounty
- or **delete it** and re-ask it (perhaps re-wording it)

But the number of [Tumbleweed badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) suggests that this *may* be an issue - or maybe those questions were too vague or too specialized to get a decent answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can update your question regularly until you get the answer. Updating will get your question to the main page. If you ask the same question it will be dublicete and will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

A related example is at [Favorite JavaScript Unit Testing Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076894/favorite-javascript-unit-testing-framework). In this case, the question is a clear duplicate of [JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-unit-test-tool-for-javascript). However, the questioner points out that things may have changed in nine months.

How should he go about getting an update?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is a perfect duplicate, then do what the other answers suggest.

But I have often seen the case where the new would-be asker is under additional constraints. In this case, it's OK to repost - but make sure to

1. Link to the original question
2. Explain how your situation is different
3. Explain why these answers don't work in your specific situation.

The point of duplicate marking is to say "You have the same problem, please use the available solutions". As long as it is obvious that you need a new solution (which is likely to be little relevant or maybe suboptimal for the original asker), it's OK to ask again.