# What if my question is technically a duplicate, but the original question was never answered?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, unanswered-questions, duplicate-questions

I'm wondering what the generally accepted/community-endorsed etiquette is in this situation. Ideally I would like to push the original question back onto the front page, as if it were a new question (because it is for me); but editing it seems strangely invasive (?). I believe I could post my own "answer" simply saying that I am having the same problem, and I *think* that would also make the question reappear on the front page; but that seems suboptimal since I wouldn't really be providing an *answer*.

Should I simply ask the question again, provide a link to the original question and accept the imminent "Closed as exact duplicate"? Perhaps that would be easiest.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-reask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> but editing it seems strangely invasive

Not at all. Take the time to do what you can to improve the original question - perhaps it was never answered simply because it wasn't as clear or specific as it might have been.

If you can write a *significantly better* question, you might just want to ask it yourself. If it then gets answered, flag the original for moderator review, and ask that they close it as a duplicate of *your* question... That way, the original author (and anyone else who happens to come across it) can still find their way to an answer.

Comment: Of course that only works if you've got editing privileges.

Comment: True. Otherwise, trying to ask a better question is pretty much the best option.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna go for it.

Comment: the problem is you can't put a bounty on some else's question, so editing there quesion is a opiton, but if it does not work, you still need your own quesiton.

Comment: What if the author of the original question already selected an answer and you didn't feel that the answer is helpful for you. The original question was good enough but the answer didn't apply to your situation (say it works on another platform). Do you also edit the original question saying that you want a more general answer or is it better to start a new question where you explain why the answer in that question wasn't helpful for you?

Comment: @Firas: the second if possible: ask a more specific question, citing the original and describing how your situation differs.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I simply ask the question again, provide a link to the original question and accept the imminent "Closed as exact duplicate"? Perhaps that would be easiest.

That would be in very poor taste -- one should never intentionally create a question knowing that it will be closed. Doing it repeatedly would be grounds for reprimands from "The Management".

You can "bump" a question back to the front page of the Active list by editing it, <strike>commenting,</strike> or even posting an answer (although this option doesn't make sense in this situation). Especially on meta, it's not unusual to see a "bump" by someone commenting "I have this problem too", with perhaps a few more diagnostic details.

Comment: wait.  commenting bumps?  since when?

Comment: Apologies, it appears it does not. I could have sworn it did though!

Comment: Sounds like editing the original is the way to go, then, assuming one's rep is high enough.

Answer (score 1):

Editing is good, when you can provide something new to the question. The technology changes etc. It is hard to guest what the case is, because you haven't put the link to the question you have in mind, so I don't know if this is the case.

I've had similar problem with my own questions not being answered. Sometimes the question is of such nature, that it has little chance to be answered or get correct answer. They are too localized or too difficult. But you should try.

Doing minor changes only to put it to the top of the list is a bit controversial, in my opinion. And doing so too many times will turn you question into community wiki.

**Bounty** is a good thing to consider. It costs the reputation but your question will get more attention. However, *more* could be not enough...

There's also another trick, that shouldn't be abused, witch **linked questions**. If you mention your question in either other question or answer (`similar problem to this is.... but` etc.), or even in the comment, your question will be displayed in the `Linked` panel on the right). However, you do that only when the question is really related to yours and providing such link would really add some value to the discussion.

I've asked similar question: [I want to feature an old question without a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112592/i-want-to-feature-an-old-question-without-a-good-answer) and I was redirected to the topic: [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). It can also be interesting for you. And note that both questions are now linked to this.