# I want to feature an old question without a good answer

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I a few times wanted to ask questions, but very similar question was already asked. The question was, however, quite old and I think many people could not respond to it because they doubted it is still actual.

I had in this situations dilemma: Ask similar question, which would be duplicate, or post a question to this answer which is actually not answer but only info that I'm interested too. Both are, I think, bad.

So I would like the 'push' flag on question or 'It's my question too' flag, so that I could mark the old question that it is still actual, still unanswered, and push it as the fresh question on the top of the list of newest questions. Is it a good idea to make such option?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page too:) Unfortunatelly I can't vote up the pointing of the duplicate as answer to my question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hav you considered adding a [bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) (Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).)

Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation and attach it to any question as a bounty. This will push it to the "featured" questions list.

You can choose a reason why you want to add a bounty, you could use the "draw attention" reason for your particular area.

[image]

Comment: But AFAIK if no new answers, bounty will be granted to the currently accepted answer, which may be not adequate for me :((

Comment: In the cases I see, where a bounty is placed on a question it always gets at least one more answer. What question do you want to bring attention to?

Comment: @lechlukasz if there will be no new answers the bounty will just disappear with no effect unless you manually grant it to existing previous answer. It will be rewarded automatically only if there will be at least one answer posted after bounty was set, with at least 2 upvotes. From the linked faq: *The criteria for an answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows: The answer must be given after the bounty was started | The answer must have a score of at least +2*