# How best to request a particular question/topic to be revisited/addressed according to latest circumstances?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, time

Sometimes there is a question of interest to me that was last active, say in 2010, and there's a desire to check if new possibilities have surfaced in 2011. I don't think a new question (How to do XXX, but in 2011) is warranted, but is there a better way than asking in the relevant chatrooms? (as the reach may not be ideal)

Comment: did you consider editing question or raising a bounty?

Comment: I am not sure if editing the question would be a good idea since it may affect the interpretation of the existing answers. Bounty is a  general solution to get more responses but I don't feel it is the best way.

Comment: well _if editing the question may affect the interpretation of the existing answers_ that makes a strong sign of a new question to me... Hm at the risk of getting close as dupe I'd rather open that new question (with the reference to old one of course)

Answer (score 4):

You could start a bounty with the reason "Current answers are outdated". This will place the question in the Featured section and hopefully draw some new answers to it.

---

[image: screenshot of bounty window]

Comment: The only problem with this is that I have no idea if current answers are outdated or not, although I would like someone to vet them and update if necessary, which is the whole point of my question.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think there are new possibilities? The answers are not enough in your opinion? Then you should, in my opinion, edit question to notice that this answers do not fully answer the problem stated in question, even if there is accepted answer.

However, if you have similar, but not the same problem, or some changes in technologies have occured, than, I think, you should ask new question linked to previous.

A real-life example in web technologies: a new version of browsers have been made (IE 9, FF 9 etc.) so you ask a question about how they work with some solution, noting that some question was made when the last version of IE was 8 etc.

I've asked something similar: [I want to feature an old question without a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112592/i-want-to-feature-an-old-question-without-a-good-answer), the answers provided me valuable hints about what is seen positive by SE users.

Comment: Technology changes every year (could be more or less frequent depending on topic), so I may want to know if subject experts have updated content (I don't know, but they may) for a certain question

Comment: Maybe a question like 'is there other way to do X as the way Y described in topic Z?'