# Ask for additional information on existing question, or start a new one?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I'm trying to solve a programming problem, and have found a solution in an existing question. However, after following the suggestions in that solution, I'm still unable to solve my problem, despite further investigation & extensive searching for answers. The Stack Overflow answer I'm using is about a year old.

Would I get a better response if I created a new question and asked my specific issue separately, linking to the old question, or should I ask for additional help in the comments / answers to the original question?

I like the idea of adding more information to the original question so that it may eventually address the issues I'm running into, but worry that no-one will notice a new comment on a question that's a year old.

I didn't find any information on this in meta SO either :)

Comment: Why not just ask a new question, reference the answer to the old one and describe - in detail - why it didn't work? See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38547/what-if-my-question-is-technically-a-duplicate-but-the-original-question-was-ne

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is situation dependant. Usually, post a new question only if:

- The new problem is not a problem with the code the old answer posted
- The new problem is not a problem with the problem of the old question
- The new question *is* significantly different to not be either an "Exact Duplicate" or "Too Localized"

Than leave a comment on the old question with a link to the new.