# Allow new users to support an existing question

Tags: feature-request, new-users, old-questions

This is in response to To [This Question(now deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572637/anyone-got-solution-of-this-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-10134920-razor-s)

**Here is the question**

> I need answer of this question:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134920/razor-sharp-annotation-by-imagemagic

Most people's initial reaction might be to down-vote and close the question.  That was my first reaction too, but then I imagined myself in the OP's shoes.

- He likely came to this site through google, seeking an answer to his question.
- He found a question like his, but the answer was unupvoted, unmarked, and apparently not a sufficient answer.

The OP was faced with a decision.  He could either

- post a duplicate(which essentially was what he did)
- Look elsewhere
- magically poof 25 reputation into existence and leave a bounty.

one of those is essentially the op being driven away.  The other is a major barrier that requires not only a potentially large investment of time, but a certain degree of knowledge about the site.

As taboo as it seems to be, the OP would probably best be served by writing a whole duplicate question.  But typically internet culture frowns on such duplicates.  Why ask a whole new question when there already was an existing question(it was closed in this particular case, but this certainly is not the only case).

All the OP tried to do is come here to seek an answer to his programming problem.  That's what I thought Stack Overflow was supposed to be for.

---

I propose that we have a button that the OP can click, to say `"I'm having this problem too"`  It would serve the purpose of duplicated questions and `I'm having this problem too` answers without the actual added noise of duplicates and uncouth answers, and without the additional penalty for asking for a solution to a problem that other users also have.

---

Judging by the comments on that question and here("oh, just leave a bounty"), the attitude around here seems to be that it ought to be harder and more costly for a user to seek an answer to a question if someone else has already posted about the same problem.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of his question? (it's deleted now)

Comment: "The OP was in a place where he needed the answer to a question that someone posted, but he didn't have sufficient reputation to edit the question and bump it," the system works. nice!

Comment: Well I was thinking about the comments.. but nevermind ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 are you suggesting that preventing people from seeking answers to questions is an example of  the system `Working`?

Comment: Gaming the system by editing a question just to bump it is just a terrible reason to edit and I want to ask you to stop doing it if that is your practice.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽  The point of the feature request is that you wouldn't have to game the system to do something so simple as seek the answer to an existing question

Comment: If that is the point you may want to rephrase your question. As it currently stands it kinda reads like you think it is common practice.

Comment: With the way the system works, I think best way for new user to raise a problem on existing question is to post a duplicate (as an independent question). Of course, this is not good if there are already too many such duplicate around, but if the problem is specific and uncommon enough, OP will get immediate attention to the problem.

Comment: I think the best answer is http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38549/192138

Comment: And see also: [What can we do for new users who want to ask a question thats already been asked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54329) (P.S., Please, system, [stop deleting modified duplicate comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified)!!)

Answer (score -2):

I don't quite understand what this feature would do.. bump the question? That's exactly what we *don't* want. If every user could, at the click of a button, bump questions to the front page mania would ensue. There's a reason why it takes three reviewers to approve an edit ;)

However, I do think that this is a problem, but I also think it's one we already have a solution for. If a new user comes along asking for a solution to an old unanswered question this is what should happen (at least, IMO):

- If the OP of the original question can be contacted and makes an attempt to update the question; someone should bounty the original, gaining it more attention (and hopefully answers)
- If the OP of the original question can't be contacted then the new user should *ask a new question* and a higher reputation user should give it a bounty to help it along (if it needs it). Once an answer has been found for the new question the original question should be closed as a duplicate of the new one.

During this process there should be experienced users helping the new user understand and work the site. Stack Exchange is a very different place than other existing Q/A sites (including forums) and we should try and help new users get to know the ropes.

(note that the original question in this case has been closed as off-topic)

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoters explained what they disliked about this method.