# Will we get a "2020: a year in moderation" post this year?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Since 2016, Shog9 has been posting every year a "year in moderation" post to every meta site with some interesting stats. However, 12 days after the last post, [he was fired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/435726). Will we get another post this year, probably by another employee?

Comment: The linked question doesn't have a clear answer... so what is it? Yes or no?

Comment: @Ian54 An earlier duplicate question not having an answer or not having an adequate answer is never a reason for asking the same question again.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38547/215590

Comment: @PolyGeo Ok...... but that's not what I meant. I am simply asking yes or no.

Comment: Why would this need reopening?