# What if I ask a duplicate question, when the first one doesn't have any answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today, I was searching for an answer to *[Initial label with 'el-select' is not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508602/initial-label-with-el-select-not-applied)* at Stack Overflow. As you see, question *exists*, but it doesn't have any proper answers. So I offered a bounty, to possess attention. Could I ask the same question rather?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you shouldn't ask a duplicate question given the fact that *you know* that a same question exists. It is not at all desired to have different copies of the same question as SE is a repository of knowledge. Duplicate questions are linked to their parent questions to have all the answers at one place.

So, if you want to get an answer to a question which already exists, you provide a bounty on it so that it gets some attention. As you have already done so, I would suggest you wait for a while and add a comment if you want to specify something related to the question.

Comment: Bounties on Meta (and many smaller sites) are largely pointless. They may attract *views* from users but they rarely attract NEW *answers*

Comment: @Mari-LouA, OP's question seems mostly about questions on non-meta sites, especially SO.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I stand by my position. Generally speaking, bounties don't work if experts, i.e high-rep users are unmotivated or simply missing from the site  to respond.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: If a bounty doesn't work, asking a new question is even less likely to work.

Comment: @Kevin Depends... If the newer question has greater detail, shows a fair amount of research, and explains why the older, supposedly "original" question is significantly outdated or inadequately describes the current problem, it's now a high-quality post. Here's an [example of such a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306242/223820) whose author is aware that other users might close it as a duplicate