# What should I do about upvoted, inactive, unanswered questions that I'm also trying to find the answer for?

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

[One question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306242/904178) has been suggested as a possible duplicate. However, my question points out a few specific scenarios that could be worth discussing. [Another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/904178) is also relevant, as it's about bringing attention to questions.

I occasionally research a programming problem, trying to solve the problem myself, and come across a Stack Overflow question, of which I'm not the author, about the problem I'm trying to solve.

However, it is:

- Unanswered
- Inactive for months or years
- Upvoted (so the Community user won't auto delete it)
- No answered duplicates

And *I*:

- Do not have enough reputation to offer a bounty
- Do not see any ways to edit and improve the post

Put another way, the chance that question will gain *any* activity by itself in a reasonable timeframe if at all is not worth discussing, and I do not have any means to promote the question myself.

So the question already exists, so if I try asking it myself, mine might get closed as a duplicate, but the existing question is useless, as it is unanswered. Also I haven't really seen the Community user's *bump to the homepage* feature in action much or at all on Stack Overflow.

In this case, what should I do? Should I post the question in such a case anyway, despite the duplicate? Would the question be closed as a duplicate of the *unanswered* question?

Comment: I guess that some of the advice offered here would apply to a post which is not your own: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046) And possibly you might find something also in [other discussions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7046).

Comment: @Martin Thanks for citing those, but as for the in the answer, I already ruled out the first 2 options, and the others can be ruled out too. Generally such questions as described are specific questions relating to a relatively unpopular technology, and there aren't as many active chat users as StackOverflow users, but those _might_ help nonetheless. And as for the second one, I don't really participate in other networks to promote such questions in.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Very similar, at least, but mine includes specific examples, such as if it's specifically very low activity and upvoted?